# swift ios cant uninstall cocoapods library

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to remove a cocoapods library.

First I edit my `Podfile` and remove this line `pod 'FBSDKShareKit'` after that I save it and run `pod install` nothing happens beside two other libs getting installed.

But the pod i removed is still left in my project, so then I try to drag the folder myself to the trash but this will result in xcode warnings when I try to build, saying that FBSDKShareKit.. is missing

Comment: Do a Clean, then close your project, then do `pod install`, then reopen the updated workspace.

Comment: @rmaddy I did as you said but I still get warnings when I run my project "Missing file" sharekit